# Update SCSS variable through an Ember color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I would like to allow an admin to change the skin of one of my sites through a color-picker affecting change on a universal sass variable.

I know that there are ways to affect live css through jQuery, etc, but I would like to actually modify the scss variable.  Here is the example:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xafajucifu/edit?html,css,js,output

As you can see, using the color picker only changes the `<body>` attribute, but I would like a method to change the `$main-color` variable so the entire `<html>` background changes.

I'm not sure if the best method involves a SAVE button or how to get it to work and am definitely open to ideas or other interpretations.

If you would prefer the actual code (instead of jsbin example) I'm working with here it is below:

**templates/settings.hbs**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Property</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$main-heading-color</td>
    <td>
      <div id="color-pick">
        {{col-pick value=mainHeadingColor}}
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**controllers/settings.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  mainHeadingColor: '0d723c'
});
```

**styles/definitions/variables.scss**

```
// project specific colors
$main-heading-color:      #0d723c;
```

**ember addon:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-colpick

Comment: The only way to change the actual file is to have a backend that receives a request and has access to write to the file.

Comment: Re @locks:  Sounds like that's the only solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCSS files are *preprocessed*, which means that they are processed at project build time to generate the native CSS files that will be interpreted by the browser, therefore the context added by the SCSS files that are not present in CSS (like variables) is **lost** after building.

In other words, what you are trying to modify doesn't exist anymore while the user is viewing your webpage/web application.

What you can do is:

- create a class (e.g. `moddable-background-color`) with the property you want to change (e.g. `background-color`).
- use this class in the elements of your application you want to be able to change at runtime.
- use jQuery to change the property value in the class (e.g. `$('moddable-background-color').css('background-color', 'selected color');`.

I guess is possible to perform some kind of request to your backend that change the SCSS variable value and forces a rebuild of all the CSS files but I don't recommend this path, it's a hard and expensive way to accomplish your goal with no real benefits over the specialized class approach.

Comment: I appreciate your reply.  In my case, there are benefits over the specialized class approach because I have a lot that depends on the variables.

For example, I have `$main-color` and `$main-color-light` and `$main-color-dark`, etc, etc all based off four main variables.  I'll mark this as an answer, but it sounds like it's gonna be a backend call.

Answer (score 0):

As I look more and more into this subject, I've found ways to emulate this.  Here are a couple great examples:

1. Modifying LESS variables through use of [cssobj](https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj), essentially using the pre-compiled variables as javascript objects:

   [Git Repo](https://github.com/futurist/cssobj-less)

   [Demo Site](https://futurist.github.io/cssobj-less/)
2. Create colors, not through pre-compiled variables, but using [`currentColor`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=currentcolor).

   [Blog Entry](http://johnm.io/blog/creating-themeable-websites-using-currentcolor/)   (CodePen included)

The actual answer is still "*No, you can't dynamically change SASS variables*", but I hope future searchees will be able to find a work-around solution like I have.